# How to create in Kicad pads with different diameter on top and bottom

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, drc

This is for a two layer design using Kicad 7.  I need to create a footprint with 4 circular PTH pads that have larger diameter on the bottom layer than on the top layer. This is to satisfy mechanical requirements at the bottom and routing requirements at the top.

I tried to add rings to the bottom layer to enlarge the diameter. That works but results in false DRC clearance violation errors since the rings are assigned to 'default' net and cannot be associated with real nets.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "This is to satisfy mechanical requirements at the bottom and routing requirements at the top."  Please explain this (especially the requirement for the bottom layer), because as far as I can recall, I've never run into that kind of issue.

Comment: Why not make the top and bottom pads the same, bigger, size (in the library)?

Comment: The design is here https://github.com/zapta/greenpak_pogo . The base of the pins at the bottom of the PCB is 2mm and at the top I need smaller diameter to be able to route between the pins.

Answer (score 0):

- Modify all of the pins with the *smaller* diameter pads that you need for routing the top layer.  You should be able to do this by double-clicking on the pad in your PCB design.
- Add solder **filled zones** (make polygons, with **pad connections set to "solid"**, either a square, rectangle, or approximating a circle shape) around the pads on the **back/bottom copper layer** that are sized per your requirements (2mm).  **Assign nets to these fills as needed for each pin.**  I would assume that a rectangular copper shape would be fine, as the actual copper exposed to the outside world is defined in the next step.
- Now add circles to the **bottom solder mask layer** to expose the copper during manufacturing of the PCB. (However, since the solder mask cares not for nets, you can use the simple filled-rectangle or filled-circle tool for this).
- If you wish to expose the bigger pads on the bottom for solder paste application (in a solder paste stencil), then also add the same 2mm filled circles/zones that you used on the solder mask layer to the bottom paste mask layer as well.

If you plan to reuse this part, then consider putting all of this into a new custom part design in your own PCB component library.

For an example of how to overlay copper regions and assign them to a pin in a KiCad library, see the "Pin 2" pad in the part "TO-252-2" in the package "Package_TO_SOT_SMD" standard KiCad PCB component library.

For an unofficial library management tutorial:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-kicad/creating-a-custom-kicad-footprint-library